# Dev C++ gives one output, but Visual studio code gives another output for same code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dev-c++

Dev C++ gives one output, but Visual studio code gives another output for same code
Why is this happening?
Any ideas, maybe it is caused by diffrent compiling options, or some mistake in code up here.
Ask if you need more info, I have no idea why this is happening.
If this happends to such a small code what will happend to a huge one.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int line[10];
int i, j;
bool growing = false;
cout << "Input 10 numbers:\n";
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    cin >> line[i];
}
if (i >= 10) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10;) {

        if (line[j] < line[j + 1]) {
            growing= true;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            growing= false;
            j = 12;
        }

    }
}

if (j >= 10 && growing== false) {
    cout << "Not growing";
}
else if (j >= 10 && growing== true
) {
    cout << "Growing";
}

}
```

Comment: What outputs do they give, and what inputs are you giving?

Comment: `if (niz[j] < niz[j + 1])` goes off the end of the array -- undefined behavior.

Comment: I am afraid you're accessing your array out of bounds here `niz[j + 1]`, that's undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the two different outputs and explained what your code is supposed to do. Also, it would help if you translate your code (variables) to English before posting it.

Comment: For input 1-10, in Dev C++ im getting rastuci = true or "Is growing", but in Visual Studio im getting rastuci=false, or "Isnt growing", for the same code.

Comment: Visual Studio https://prnt.sc/1161sky  DevC++ https://prnt.sc/1161sy6

Comment: @gmijo47 fix the Undefined Behaviour and try again.  UB means that anything can happen and nothing can be reasoned about.

Comment: I ll give it a try, then notify @here

Comment: `line[j + 1]` with `j=9` goes out of array boundaries. That's Undefined Behaviour (UB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution. start the variable `j` at 1 and compare `line[j - 1]` with `line[j]`. `j` will be max 9 in this case.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int line[10];
    bool growing = false;
    cout << "Input 10 numbers:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cin >> line[i];
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
    {

        if (line[j - 1] < line[j])
        {
            growing = true;
            continue; // start next iteration and skips line 22 and 23
        }
        growing = false;
        break; // stops the loop and moves to line 25
    }

    if (growing)
    {
        cout << "Growing";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not Growing";
    }
}
```

or make it even simpler:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int line[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> line[i];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (!(line[i - 1] < line[i]))
        {
            std::cout << "Not Growing\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Growing";
}
```